# saving data with time in database column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, date-formatting

from UI when I am sending `date`, then in `database` I can see `date without timestamp`. When I do

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
```

then I can see `timestamp` as well. But it is session specific. I want this change parmanent.

I want `timestamp` permanently in database along with `date`. in logfile it is displaying only date but not time.

what changes I need to do in `database`? Is there any problem in my understanding

Comment: I usually just convert the date to a timestamp to see the time component.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you Gordon..actually its legacy system so not possible to change datatype. any other alternative?

Comment: Can't you configure SQL Developer to display DATE values in a pre-defined format independent of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`?

Comment: actually I need  to print date and time in log file. in log file it is printing only date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, for the whole database & for all users? Talk to your DBA, they should know it. That would be the `nls_date_format` initialization parameter.

Alternatively, create the `after logon` database trigger which will modify that value, e.g.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_dflt_date_format
  2    after logon on database
  3  begin
  4    execute immediate q'[alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss']';
  5  end;
  6  /

Trigger created.
```

What's current format?

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
--------
13.07.20
```

OK, logout and login again:

```
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

C:\temp>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Pon Srp 13 16:55:08 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
13.07.2020 16:55:12

SQL>
```

Looks OK.

---

However: topic title says:

> saving data with time in database column

Unless you "remove" the time component (e.g. by truncating the value, such as `trunc(sysdate)`), Oracle will store both date and time. It is just the way you *display* it.

One option is to use `alter session` (as you already know), another is to use `to_char` function with desired format mask, e.g.

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss yyyy-mm-dd') right_now from dual;

RIGHT_NOW
-------------------
16:59:29 2020-07-13

SQL>
```